# How to scrape pop ups using selenium with multiple windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

From This Website: https://etherscan.io/address/0x6eed5b7ec85a802428f7a951d6cc1523181c776a#writeContract. **1.The program first clicks on  "Connect to Web"** [image]. **2.Then I want to click on "Wallet Connect"** [image].

Currently, Wallet Connect only clicks if `driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://bings.com","_blank");''')` is removed.
The `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])` only switches to the popup containing the wallets when there is only one tab. How do I switch to the pop up when there is a another tab (or any number of tabs); i.e. when `driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://bings.com","_blank");''')` is included in the script.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Dec  3 20:44:06 2021

@author: Main
"""

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Main\Documents\Work\Projects\Scraping Websites\extra\chromedriver')
 
 driver.get("https://etherscan.io/address/0x6eed5b7ec85a802428f7a951d6cc1523181c776a#writeContract")
driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://bings.com","_blank");''')#code works only if this is removed

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#btnCookie"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#writecontractiframe")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#connectStatus"))))

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(1))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, """//button[@onclick="connectWalletConnect('writecontractiframe')"]"""))).click()
```

Comment: it only outputs 2 handles, one for each tab, there is no handle for the pop up

Comment: The popup is also not in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/address/0x6eed5b7ec85a802428f7a951d6cc1523181c776a#writeContract")
driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://bings.com","_blank");''')#code works only if this is removed

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#btnCookie"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#writecontractiframe")))
elem=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#connectStatus")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
driver.switch_to.default_content

##wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(1))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, """//button[@onclick="connectWalletConnect('writecontractiframe')"]"""))).click()
```

You never really closed the window for there to be number of windows to be 1.
Also you never left the iframe.